# DevExpress ASPxGridView has to be bound on every Callback/Postback

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, devexpress

We are using ASPxGridView in a web project. But each time any callback or postback request is sent, the grid needs to be rebound to its data source. Doing so has impacted the performance of the website.
Is there any other way we can do this?
Using DevEx version 15.1.6
DataSource is a data table from  MS SQL Server.

Comment: are you affect the datatable to your ASPxGridView  in "Page_Load" ?Can you post the code of affectation of your datatable?

Comment: from the Devx Documentation: *"ASPxGridView has built-in Cache. If the EnableRowCache setting is enabled, the Cache stores data of visible rows (rows that belong to a current data page of ASPxGridView). This allows to aviod additional data binding."*